# Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of ""

Tags: javascript

I've this html page with a module ...

```
<html>
    <body>
        <hello-world color="blue" />
        <hello-world color="red" />
        <hello-world />
        <script type="module">
            import { HelloWorld } from './HelloWorld.js'
            window.customElements.define('hello-world', HelloWorld)
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

... and the module content is ...

```
export class HelloWorld extends HTMLElement {
    get color () {
        return this.getAttribute('color') || 'gray'
    }

    set color (value) {
        this.setAttribute('color', value)
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            const div = document.createElement('div')
            div.textContent = 'Hello World!!!'
            div.style.color = this.color
            this.appendChild(div)
        });
    }
}
```

I run a PHP server using `php -S localhost:8888 -t .` and all works fine:

[image]

Instead, ... if I move module in `./main.mjs` file with content ...

```
import { HelloWorld } from './HelloWorld.js'
window.customElements.define('hello-world', HelloWorld)
```

... changing the html part in ...

```
<html>
    <body>
        <hello-world color="blue" />
        <hello-world color="red" />
        <hello-world />
        <script type="module" src="main.mjs"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

... I get the following error:

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Why? May I fix it? How?

Answer (score 0):

You may send the proper content-type (text/javascript) to specify you are sending js files.

exemple with a basic server in node:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs')
const requestListener = function (req, res) {
  f = req.url === '/' ? 'index.html' : 'main.mjs'

  // commenting that block will give an empty mime type and module will not be loaded
  if (f === 'main.mjs') {
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/javascript')
  }
  res.writeHead(200)
  return fs.createReadStream(f).pipe(res)
}

const server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(8080);
console.log('listening: http://localhost:8080')
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="junk">loading failed</div>
  <script type="module" src="main.mjs"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
document.getElementById('junk').innerHTML = 'loading ok'
```

see [Troubleshooting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)

Answer (score 0):

PHP's simple built-in server doesn't have a MIME type registered for `.mjs` files. It's not a common extension and is typically only used for ES6 modules in Node.js (and isn't needed there any more thanks to the [type option in `package.json`](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_package_json_type_field)).

Rename the file to have a `.js` extension again and your HTTP server will send the correct Content-Type for it.

Comment: Next to node.js, there's also jasmine requiring .mjs file to support ES6 modules. So renaming might not be an option if you want to use the files in multiple use cases...